# redshift color adjustment with hardware/software cursor

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xrandr

I'm running [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) (with [Con Kolivas' ck1 patchset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux-ck), although that shouldn't affect this issue) and using the [proprietary Nvidia graphics driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nvidia), currently at version 313.26 (my card is a GeForce GTX 670).

I use [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) to adjust the color temperature of my screen for more comfortable/healthy viewing; it uses XRandR to do its thing. The problem is, it doesn't affect the cursor. So when I'm using my computer at night, the whole screen has a nice soft color, but the mouse cursor is rendered at the normal 6500K, which is really jarring. I can't provide a screenshot because the color adjustment only applies to the monitor.

The reason for the cursor ignoring the color change is that the cursor is rendered by the graphics hardware, and so it bypasses the processing that redshift applies. This is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/724078) and the author of the program basically says he can't do anything about it.

I've tried enabling software cursor rendering using `HWCursor off` or `SWCursor on` (or both). This makes the cursor affected by the color adjustment, as expected, but the cursor is really glitchy. It lags, disappears every few seconds, and leaves strange artifacts wherever it goes. It's pretty much unusable.

On my laptop, using the [open source Intel driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics), the cursor is properly adjusted by redshift and it renders fine (no lag, artifacts, etc.). So that machine is either (a) using a software cursor which is working much better for some reason, or (b) using a hardware cursor which is properly applying the color adjustment. I don't know which it is, and I'm not sure how to find out (suggestions welcome).

So I need to either get the hardware cursor to obey redshift or get the software cursor to stop glitching. I'm thinking the latter would be easier, since I've seen many people with the former problem and haven't seen anyone with a solution. In any case, I'm not sure how to approach either problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/)?

Comment: f.lux has the same problem. It's not anything about redshift that causes the problem, it's just that the hardware cursor bypasses pretty much any color adjustment. I've seen people have the same problem with f.lux on Windoze, even.